# Изменить цвет сразу нескольких svg элементов

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Имеется svg иконка состоящая из нескольких элементов

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="-27 28 90 90" style="enable-background:new -27 28 90 90;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#EAEAEA;}
 .st1{fill:none;stroke:#5ACCB6;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1:hover {stroke:#F79F2B;}
</style>
<circle id="trg" class="st0" cx="18" cy="73" r="45"/>
<g>
 <polyline class="st1" points="14.1,63.6 18,73.9 29.7,79  "/>
 <polyline class="st1" points="-0.3,75.6 -3.9,82.7 -11.4,78.9  "/>
 <path class="st1" d="M-4.4,82C-9.3,69.3-3,54.9,9.7,50s27.1,1.4,32,14.1s-1.4,27.1-14.1,32c-9,3.5-18.9,1.3-25.6-4.8"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

В примере каждый элемент по отдельности меняет свой цвет при наведении. Как добиться чтобы цвет менялся при наведении сразу у всей иконки? тег `<set>` хром запрещает использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант смотреть `hover` контейнера

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="-27 28 90 90" style="enable-background:new -27 28 90 90;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#EAEAEA;}
 .st1{fill:none;stroke:#5ACCB6;stroke-width:4;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    g:hover .st1 {stroke:#F79F2B;}
</style>
<circle id="trg" class="st0" cx="18" cy="73" r="45"/>
<g>
 <polyline class="st1" points="14.1,63.6 18,73.9 29.7,79  "/>
 <polyline class="st1" points="-0.3,75.6 -3.9,82.7 -11.4,78.9  "/>
 <path class="st1" d="M-4.4,82C-9.3,69.3-3,54.9,9.7,50s27.1,1.4,32,14.1s-1.4,27.1-14.1,32c-9,3.5-18.9,1.3-25.6-4.8"/>
</g>
</svg>
```